# Example sentence with 酌む

Tags: words

I'm trying to learn the verb 酌む (to pour sake, to serve sake), but I can only find a few sentences with this verb, and in these few sentences the verb 酌む doesn't appear to express (in theory) its main meaning: to serve sake, but derivative forms of 酌む like 酌み交わす or expressions like 意を酌む. So I would like you to give me an example sentence (or some if you please) with 酌む (not 酌み交わす) meaning "to pour sake, to serve sake".

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Does [this](http://yourei.jp/%E9%85%8C%E3%82%80) help? Or [try this with 酌む](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/string_search)

Comment: @sundowner Thanks for the links, although what I would like the most is just an example sentence with no need to have a context to be fully understood, unlike the majority of sentences that are extracts from corpuses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was browsing through the corpuses, and probably the cause of your difficulty is just that 酌む is not really used in ordinary conversations.

- 友達と酒を酌んだ I had a drink with a friend
- 酒を酌みながらテレビを見た I drank sake watching TV

are not particularly weird, but normally I would say 友達と酒を**飲んだ**/酒を**飲み**ながらテレビを見た.

---

酌み交わす may be used more frequently, but still sounds a bit dramatic.

- いつか子供と酒を酌み交わしたい I want to drink with my children some day

Again, 酒を飲みたい sounds more usual to me.

---

On the other hand, the sense of *understand/guess* is usual.

- 事情を酌んで considering the circumstances
- 意図を酌む guess/estimate the intention

---

[Edit]

- 水をコップに汲む pour water into a glass

is perfectly normal. In the same way,

- 日本酒をコップに酌む pour sake into a glass

should be fine. In this case what happens is only pouring, so 酌む can be replaced only by そそぐ（注ぐ） or つぐ.

I said *should* because for some reason I don't see any uses of 酌む with explicitly mentioning where sake is being poured. There may be hidden rules for use of 酌む that makes 日本酒を**コップに**酌む ungrammatical, in which case 酒を酌む always means 酒を飲む.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Then, although not in an ordinary conversation, but for example in a novel, could I always replace 飲む by 酌む? Does 酌む mean "to drink (sake)"?

Comment: Almost yes, except for the sense of _consider_ etc. (which is synonymous for [斟酌する](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%96%9F%E9%85%8C/#je-37672) ).  I say _almost_ because of the sentences I added in the edit.

Comment: Ok, I see! Thank you so much for your help. :)