# Does a cross in Weblio represent an obsolete kanji?

Tags: dictionary, symbols

After looking at [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/90171/example-sentence-with-%E9%85%8C%E3%82%80) I went
[weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%85%8C%E3%82%80) to look up the meaning of 酌む. The heading for the entry looks like this:

> く・む【×汲む／酌む】

I'm wondering what the cross next to 汲む means. I've seen this in a few things I've looked up on Weblio and never managed to figure it out.

My guess is that it means 汲む is obsolete and I should use 酌む instead, but I'm not at all sure. Indeed, in the comment I just saw on the linked question from @Chocolate, I'm now certain my theory is wrong.

I assume Weblio has a page explaining its symbols but my Japanese isn't good enough to find it.

Comment: https://www.weblio.jp/shogakukan.jsp#5

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the helpful links/answers. Not sure whether to close the question. I'm tempted to self answer if no one provides a formal answer just so that link has a permanent reference.

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing and been confused by it too.  So, I'd be interested in seeing what sort of feedback you get.

Comment: For example, the entry in my dictionary is くむ[酌む*＜汲む] where "*" is actually a bullet. (I should add that this written using 縦書き) Not sure what this is supposed to mean and no where else in the entry are distinctions drawn between which kanji to use for which definition.  I had to go to my 漢和辞典 to get any further nuance.

Comment: More specifically [２] 常用漢字
見出しに相当する漢字で、常用漢字表にない漢字には「×」、常用漢字音訓表にない読みの場合には「▽」を左肩に付した。 Most Japanese dictionaries contain this kind of information and explain in the first pages what symbols are used to indicate them. I checked two dictionaries at hand, one used × and the other ▼ for non-常用漢字.